Input text formation for Fine tuning LLM with hugging face
I am new in this field and working on a school project where I'm trying to fine tune a model with my own dataset. I want the model to predict treatment from the data I have provided. Using Llama 2-7b model with hugging face library.
def create_input_text(example):return (f"Symptoms: {example['symptoms']}. Diagnosis: {example['diagnoses']}.  
"f"Predict the required medical treatment.") 

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: {'input_text': create_input_text(x), 'labels': x['treatment']}) 
test_dataset = test_dataset.map(lambda x: {'input_text': create_input_text(x), 'labels': x['treatment']})

def tokenize_function(examples):tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(examples['input_text'],padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=128)

tokenized_labels = tokenizer( 
examples['labels'], padding='max_length', truncation=True,   max_length=128)     

tokenized_inputs["labels"] = tokenized_labels["input_ids"]     
return tokenized_inputs

after the training
def predict(input_text):inputs = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt", padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=128)

outputs = model.generate(**inputs, pad_token_id=tokenizer.pad_token_id,                            max_new_tokens=150)   

prediction = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)  
return prediction

the code is running without any error but when I want to check the output of the model, the model does not generate anything new. It just printing out the input text.
I was expecting from the model to generate new treatment based on the data that was provided instead of just imitating the answers from the datasets.
Any suggestion to acquire the expected result from the experts? Thank you in advance.
